# Given $ f(x,y) = \begin{cases} e^{-\frac{x^2}{y^2}} & y \neq 0 \\ 0 & y = 0 \\ \end{cases} $

Tags: analysis, limits, continuity

$$ f(x,y) = \begin{cases}        e^{-\frac{x^2}{y^2}} & y \neq 0 \\       0 & y = 0 \\  \end{cases} $$. Is this function continuous everywhere? Or it is not continuous at some points?

Answer (score 0):

HINT:  Try obvious paths to see if you get different results.   Some trial paths that seem obvious: $x=y$,  $y=x^2$.